# Como puedo obtener la fecha de 3 meses antes a la fecha actual en SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift

Hola espero pudieran apoyarme, quisiera tener seleccionada en el DatePicker() , la fecha de 3 meses atras, pero me causa problemas la fecha previousDate ya que la selection que ocupa el DatePicker() es Date() y no he podido setearla directamente

Aquí dejo mi codigo:

```
struct DatePickerMovements: View {
@State private var currentDate: Date = Date()

let previousDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())

var body: some View {
    DatePicker("", selection: previousDate, in: ...currentDate, displayedComponents: .date)
        .labelsHidden()
        .font(Font.appFontSemiBold(size: 16))
        .foregroundColor(.textColor)
        .background(Color.clear)
        .accentColor(.accentColor)
        .clipped()
}
```

}

me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según la alerta que muestras (Cannot convert value of tyoe 'Date?' to expected argument type 'Binding<Date>'), la pregunta estaría mal planteada. No tienes un problema para calcular la fecha puesto que `previousDate` no tiene ninguna alerta. El problema es que estás haciendo un mal uso del DatePicker, al margen de las fechas. Por favor, replantea la pregunta para que otras personas puedan localizar una respuesta correcta según la pregunta formulada.

Comment: Entiendo , creo que si la plantee mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu ejemplo, no es `currentDate` quien almacena el valor del DatePicker sino la variable `previousDate`, y por lo tanto debería ser una variable que pudiera mutar su valor. De ahí que te pida un `property wrapper` como `@State` para fingir la mutabilidad de la variable al almacenar la fecha. Es decir, no estás pasando los parámetros de forma correcta en el DatePicker.

```
struct DatePickerMovements: View {
 @State private var currentDate: Date = Date()

  let previousDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())

  var body: some View {
    DatePicker("", selection: previousDate, in: ...currentDate, displayedComponents: .date)
  }
}
```

En este ejemplo, tenemos un rango desde 3 meses atrás hasta los próximos 5 días.

Al seleccionar una fecha dentro del rango (limitRange), se actualiza el valor de la variable declarada como `@State` y permitimos actualizar el valor gracias a que accedemos al `binding` desde el DatePicker anteponiendo el $ (**$**selectedDate). Al pasar un nuevo valor al binding, se refresca la vista y se actualiza el texto posterior con el nuevo valor sin el $ (selectedDate), porque no enlaza al binding sino a su valor final.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI


struct DatePickerMovements: View {
    @State var selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -10, to: Date())!

    var limitRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let threeMonthsAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -3, to: Date())!
        let fiveDaysFromNow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 5, to: Date())!

        return threeMonthsAgo...fiveDaysFromNow
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, in: limitRange, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
            Text("Your selectedDate: \(selectedDate)")
        }
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
let view = DatePickerMovements()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
// PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(DatePickerMovements())
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta , mas bien lo que ocupo es la fecha de 3 meses antes este seleccionada

Comment: Tan sólo tienes que cambiar la fecha inicial, que es 'selectedDate'. He cambiado el código para empezar en la fecha actual menos 10 días. Será la fecha por defecto en el DatePicker dentro del rango indicado.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Carlos me funciono bastante bien